# If the $A^*A\leq BB^*$ and $B$ is a compact operator, then the operator $A$ is compact

Tags: compact-operators

I am a student of mathematics and professor left us today for homework this example:

If the $A^*A\leq BB^*$ and $B$ is a compact operator, then the operator $A$ is compact. Prove this. ($A^*$ hermitian adjoint operator)

Thanks very much for your help. Previously thank you for your solution.

Comment: What does $\leq$ mean here?

Comment: think that has to do with the relation of the smallest common equivalent

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Might be it means $BB^* - AA^*$ is nonnegative.